# Convert Records To Special XML Objects

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

I need to convert one of rows to xml with certain format as the following :

```
<root>
    <TableID>101</TableID>
    <TableName>Teacher</TableName>
    <Objects>
        <Object>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>X</name>
            <value>abc</value>
            <DataType>Int</DataType>
        </Object>
        <Object>
            <id>2</id>
            <name>Y</name>
            <value>def</value>
            <DataType>char</DataType>
        </Object>
    </Objects>
</root>
```

my attempt as the below, mainly i have issue with how i can create (Objects) node:

```
DECLARE @TableID int  = 1,
@TableName NVARCHAR(200)

SELECT  @TableID TableID ,
@TableName TableName ,
( SELECT    '1' "id" ,
'x' "name" ,
abc "value" ,
'DataType' "DataType"
FOR
XML PATH('Object') ,
TYPE
)
FROM    Teacher AS T1
FOR     XML PATH('root') ,
TYPE
```

Comment: Please add your table schema.

Comment: Can you show the table structure

Comment: Please show some sample data and your query

Comment: CREATE TABLE Teacher
    (
      id INT ,
      name VARCHAR(10) ,
      value VARCHAR(100)
    )

Comment: From where you will get table id, table name and datatype

Comment: these data stored in other table can you please help me the query structure ?

Comment: @halfer please find my attempt :

SELECT  TableID ,
TableName ,
( SELECT    '1' "id" ,
'x' "name" ,
abc "value" ,
'Type' "xtype"
FOR
XML PATH('Object') ,
TYPE
)
FROM    Teacher AS T1
FOR     XML PATH('root') ,
TYPE

Comment: Great. May I trouble you to edit it into your question using a formatted block please? Some input data and the output you actually get will also be essential to understanding the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite unclear... But my magic crystal ball told me that you tried something like this:

This code is fully *hard-coded* and produces exactly the needed result. But this is quite probably not, what you are looking for (*convert records to special xml objects*):

```
DECLARE @TableID INT = 1,
        @TableName NVARCHAR(200)='Teacher';

SELECT  @TableID TableID ,
        @TableName TableName ,
        ( 
         SELECT u.*
         FROM
         (
             SELECT    '1' "id" ,
                       'x' "name" ,
                       'abc' "value" ,
                       'DataType' "DataType"
             UNION ALL
             SELECT    '2' "id" ,
                       'Y' "name" ,
                       'def' "value" ,
                       'char' "DataType"
         ) AS u
        FOR XML PATH('Object'),ROOT('Objects') ,TYPE
        )
FOR XML PATH('root') ,TYPE;
```

From your title I take, that the data is coming from a table. To *mock-up* a test scenario, I use a declared table variable and fill it with your data.

The next time you ask a question here on SO, this part should've be done by you. Your chance for a good answer is highly increased: [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

```
DECLARE @TableID INT = 1,
        @TableName NVARCHAR(200)='Teacher';

DECLARE @Teacher TABLE(id INT IDENTITY,name VARCHAR(100),value VARCHAR(100),DataType VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @Teacher VALUES ('x','abc','DataType')
                           ,('Y','def','char');


SELECT  @TableID TableID ,
        @TableName TableName ,
        ( 
         SELECT t.*
         FROM @Teacher AS t
         FOR XML PATH('Object'),ROOT('Objects') ,TYPE
        )
FOR XML PATH('root') ,TYPE;
```

Both have the same result

```
<root>
  <TableID>1</TableID>
  <TableName>Teacher</TableName>
  <Objects>
    <Object>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>x</name>
      <value>abc</value>
      <DataType>DataType</DataType>
    </Object>
    <Object>
      <id>2</id>
      <name>Y</name>
      <value>def</value>
      <DataType>char</DataType>
    </Object>
  </Objects>
</root>
```